# Why is this contradictory behavior from the && operator happening?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const {DEMO, PORT, LOCAL} = process.env;
const socketAddress = (DEMO & LOCAL)? `http://${hostname}:${PORT}`: `wss://${hostname}`;
```

DEMO is false, PORT is undefined, and LOCAL is true

Hostname is `http://9f9cbf19.ngrok.io`

I double checked all values through console.log

Because `(DEMO && LOCAL) === (false && true) === false`, the second expression `wss://${hostname}` should assigned to `socketAddress`.

This unbelievably doesn't happen though.

Below is some stuff I logged and what I got back in my console.

```
`console.log('DEMO '+DEMO+' LOCAL '+LOCAL)`
```

in my console: `DEMO false LOCAL true`

very normal

`console.log('DEMO && LOCAL returns '+(DEMO && LOCAL))`

In my console: `DEMO && LOCAL returns true`

NOT normal. How is this even possible

```
`console.log('false && true returns '+(false&&true))`
```

In my console: `false && true returns false`

Perfectly normal... So why doesn't `DEMO && LOCAL` return the same if DEMO is false and LOCAL is true as shown by my earlier log?

I just found that `LOCAL && DEMO` returns false.

How can `LOCAL && DEMO === false` and `DEMO & LOCAL === true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are assigning from process.env which is a string datatype.

```
console.log("false" && "true") //will print true.
```

convert the values to boolean values

Comment: i just found that LOCAL && DEMO returns false.

how can LOCAL && DEMO === false and DEMO&&LOCAL === true

Comment: `"true" && "false" == "false"`, `"false" && "true" == "true"`. `&&` returns the second operand if the first operand is truthy. Since both operands are truthy (as are all non-empty strings), you get the second operand, which is the string `"false"` in the first case, and the string `"true"` in the second. You really should distinguish strings and booleans.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like DEMO and LOCAL are strings rather than booleans. Note that console.log(false) and console.log('false') produce exactly the same output.

You should avoid using the && operator on them until you have parsed them to proper boolean variables, such as:

```
const DEMO = process.env.DEMO == 'true';
const LOCAL = process.env.LOCAL == 'true';
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
```

then proceed with your ternary operator.